# Stuck at getting array from another thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have a small, but very strange problem...
I need to read fragments from file and place them into array, which is out of reading thread, but when i wants to get them from current thread, i'm getting empty arrray.
My brain crashed at this stuff:

```
private int fragmentSize = 262144, fragmentCacheElements = 32, fragmentCacheUpdates = 0;
// Cache 8Mb (265Kb*32)(262144*32)
private String[] fragmentCache;
private boolean needCacheUpdate, end;
private Thread cacheThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    String[] fCache = new String[fragmentCacheElements];

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!end) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCacheElements; ++i) {
                fCache[i] = new String(loadFragment(i + fragmentCacheUpdates * fragmentCacheElements));
            }
            while (true) {
                if (needCacheUpdate) {
                    ++fragmentCacheUpdates;
                    fragmentCache = fCache;
                    // fragment[0] != null
                    needCacheUpdate = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    fragmentCache = new String[fragmentCacheElements];
    cacheThread.start();
    updateCache();
    // Notifying client
}

// Getting fragment from cache to send it to client
// AND WHY fragment[0] == null ???
private String getCache(int id)
{
    if (id >= fragmentCacheUpdates * fragmentCacheElements) {
        updateCache();
    }
    return fragmentCache[id - (fragmentCacheUpdates - 1) * fragmentCacheElements];
}

private void updateCache()
{
    needCacheUpdate = true;
    while (true) {
        if (!needCacheUpdate) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @iccthedral, You mean do it in cycle?
Like

`for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCacheElements; ++i)
    {
        fragmentCache[i] = fCache[i];
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
fragmentCache = Arrays.copyOf(fCache, fCache.length);
```

Comment: Ahh.. It was because i copied the link to fCache, but not value!
You genius, thanks!